# Vectorizing a loop via numpy for qlearner/dyna-q implementation

Tags: numpy, vectorization, q-learning

I have a 100 x 4 sized 2d numpy array A (q table), and another array B (experience table) that gets continuously updated with a 4 element tuple (representing state, action, state_prime, reward). I need to randomly select a row from array B, extract the 4 elements, and run a function update(s, a, s', r) that updates array A with the 4 elements as arguments. I need to do this x times.

My current implementation involves a for loop and python list:

```
array B = []
given s, a, s', r
B.append(s, a, s', r)
for i in range x:
  r = random.choice(B)
  update(r[0], r[1], r[2], r[3])
```

I would like to get rid of the for loop and vectorize the solution but only if it's faster than using python lists. I've tried creating an empty np.array([]) for B, creating a (0, 4) sized np array and vstacking, shuffling, etc. But my current way of using python lists is the fastest by far.

Edit1: I do not know what to initialize the rows of B to thus I cannot use index to write in the tuple.

Comment: Do not use arrays as though they were lists.  That's slow.

Comment: Can't you make `B` `np.zeros((100,4))`?  That's certainly better than that `empty({})` and repeated stacking.  But the real trick is to do `update` for all rows at once.

Comment: I doubt the `update` function can be vectorized. Vectorization generally means operating on *independent* items (at least in Numpy). Here, the update function is called iteratively to update the Q-table. Besides, I expect the update function to be the bottleneck and not the loop itself. Even if it would be possible, which is not, vectorization cannot be efficiently done on black-box functions. The function needs to be rewritten (or adapted if compiler-based solution are used).

Comment: The update function is the SARSA reinforcement learning Algorithm, it cannot be rewritten.